# How can I increase my heavy armour quickly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a level 80 mage whom wears heavy armour but it is slowing my character down too much. I've got the  heavy armour skill to 35 and need to increase it so I can get the perk that makes the armour weigh nothing.

How can I speed up leveling this skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are struggling is that you are only getting hit by arrows and ice spears....

just wear full set of heavy armor and use melee attacks...like swords or daggers.....the way heavy armor works is when you get hit your level in heavy armor increases.

Comment: Just lower your game difficulty and get hit by giants with the heal spell and the mouse button held down.